# Gunicorn error 203 while setting up django project

Tags: django, gunicorn

I try setting up a django project with nginx and gunicorn but get a gunicorn error 203:
[image]

My installation is located at path /webapps/sarlex and all project files are owned by user "sarlex" and group "webapps".
The virtualenv is located at /webapps/sarlex/environment.
Gunicorn is located at /webapps/sarlex/environment/bin/ and owned by user sarlex.

Gunicorn configuration is set in /webapps/sarlex/gunicorn_start.sh:

```
NAME="sarlex"                                     # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/sarlex/                        # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/sarlex/run/gunicorn.sock        # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=sarlex                                       # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=9                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sarlex.settings            # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=sarlex.wsgi                    # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /webapps/sarlex/environment/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
--log-file=-
```

Executing gunicorn_start.sh works with environment activated and deactivated.

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service is owned by root and has this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
User=sarlex
Group=webapps
WorkingDirectory=/webapps/sarlex
ExecStart=/webapps/sarlex/gunicorn_start.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried to replace "User=Sarlex" with "User=root" but still get the same error.

The correct gunicorn it taken

[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is your question?

- The export for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` was awkward.
- Enclose expressions and variable references in double quotes

```sh
NAME="sarlex"                                     # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/sarlex/                        # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/sarlex/run/gunicorn.sock        # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=sarlex                                       # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=9                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sarlex.settings            # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=sarlex.wsgi                    # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
source /webapps/sarlex/environment/bin/activate
cd "$DJANGODIR"
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH="$DJANGODIR":$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR="$(dirname $SOCKFILE)"
test -d "$RUNDIR" || mkdir -p "$RUNDIR"

# Start your Django Unicorn
exec gunicorn "${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application" \
  --name "$NAME" \
  --workers "$NUM_WORKERS" \
  --user="$USER" --group="$GROUP" \
  --bind="unix:$SOCKFILE" \
  --log-level=debug \
--log-file=-
```

Please show `/var/log/nginx/` error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Django failed starting because in one of my scripts I wrote "admin" in a path instead of "Admin".
This didn't cause a problem on my windows PC where I am developing my code.